# In what situation can I post a similar question without it being closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, etiquette, languages

I came across two different situations which seem to require a reasonable duplication of a question:

1. Is it allowed to post the same question related to the same issue, but in two different languages?

   For example, I don't live in an English speaking country and I have a laptop that may require country specific model information or I want to make the search for my answer more efficient, making it visible to a greater number of people.
2. Is it allowed to post the same question (but maybe with different emphases) when the question requires a multidisciplinary approach?

   As an example, I want to make a question about bio programming languages which lies in a tiny line between two subjects involved.

To be more general, when can asking a duplicate question be considered acceptable?

**Edit**

The first situation is the point that I want to consider with more details, since this question was flagged as a duplicate and I read all answers of the original question but it doesn't seam to be clear about the different languages and countries issue.

I have an Inspiron 14R 5437, which I think appears only in Brazilian market, its default ps/2 keyboard keeps pressing its keys randomly. I followed the most voted answer of this question:

[How can I disable my laptop's built-in keyboard in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard-in-windows-7)

I ended up with both, my touchpad and keyboard disabled and I don't have an external mouse to plug-in and the cursor wasn't showing up anyway. I applied the previous configuration and the touchpad, cursor and default keyboard are back, with the same problem back indeed.

I am posting this here before to do it at Super User, because I want to be sure that it won't be flagged as a duplicate there (it happens to be a question with many duplicates) and to address more general cases of non-English speaking users.

Comment: Oh, you're asking about posting a similar question *on the same site*, rather than on different sites? Apologies, I misunderstood you; in that case this certainly isn't a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: Thank you for reconsidering, I used the wrong word since the portugues Stack Overflow appears as its own site, now I see the name of the list is 'Communities', thank you anyway.

Comment: No problem, it's my fault for not reading clearly enough, I've voted to reopen your question